# Login storage suggestions

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm looking to log all logins by a user. Something Simple like `userid, date, ip`should I just create a database with each table being a user followed by each row being a login? If there were 100's of users would there be any negative effects of such a method? Is this the way it's done in practice? or is there a better way?

Comment: login to what?  OS?  Database?  Web site?  What's the volume?  A million a day?  A million a year?

Comment: Website, lets say.. a million a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a separate table for each user. The table should encompass all logins by all users:

```
CREATE TABLE logins (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    log_time DATETIME, 
    ip INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

mysql> DESCRIBE logins;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| log_time | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: If the Table has 100,000 entries, what would be the best way of searching all entries by a particular user to find a value?

Comment: To get all logins of user 5: `SELECT * FROM logins WHERE user_id = 5`.